# reading with CGPDFDocumentRef and saving PDF

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator

i am reading PDF files using  CGPDFDocumentRef but now i want to **save that PDF file in my iPhone**, how to do it, what to use ? if any example is giving it will be highly appreciated. **Thanks** :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the way Apple does it in [their Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html) (specifically Listing 13-4).