# Saving a CGPDFDocumentRef to File

Tags: iphone, pdf, nsdata, cgpdfdocument

I am having a hard time searching for this question, is there no one can answer this question?
I am hoping for a good answer with example. follow this question [iPhone - pdf encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763942/iphone-pdf-encryption) but I think PDFDocument class only exists in mac os.and this is similar to this question [reading with CGPDFDocumentRef and saving PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729911/reading-with-cgpdfdocumentref-and-saving-pdf) haven't got an answer. :(

Answer (score -1):

Check out listing 13-4 in [Apple's Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html).

Which I found when I looked [at this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370292/create-pdf-inapp-ipad).

Comment: the programming guide shows how to create a PDF file, instead what I want is convert a CGRectPDFDocumentRef to NSData and then save to file, is this possible? Because I have already got a CGPDFDocumentRef (got from url) and want to change the password and then save to file again.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this already? Thats the same thing in want  to do.